MLRC-2025 Participation Timeline Doubt
I am planning to participate in MLRC-2025, I got updated about it late. I have attached the website link of time-lines for MLRC-2025.
My doubt is regarding the deadline for paper submission to TMLR (first stage in the process). Like how much time is left for me to complete the stage-1. In the timeline, they've mentioned the deadline to share the intent Deadline to share your intent to submit a TMLR paper to MLRC: February 21st, 2025
Pls help me interpret the timelines rightly.
Thanks...

I’m voting to close this question because I think it's off-topic.
